# Set BarButtonItem (Left) as Image from URL

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

Im fairly new to swift and im struggling to set a bar button item as an image which pulls from the Sign-In function that has created a variable 'profilePicImage'.

```
  var profilePicUrl: URL?
```

```
       @IBAction func signIn(_ sender: Any)  {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: self) { user, error in
                guard error == nil else { return }
                guard let user = user else { return }

                self.profilePicUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 320)
```

Then, in the Main ViewController where i want to display this image i have created an Outlet for the BarButtonItem called 'profileButton'

```
    @IBOutlet weak var profileButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

however from here i come unstuck. any help offered i would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Are the `signIn` function and the `profileButton` property in the same class?

Comment: You should be able to access the authenticated user from the MainViewController. In the google developer documentation, it says that "Once the user has authenticated and authorized access to the scopes you request, you can access user profile information through the GIDGoogleUser object." https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people#retrieving_user_information

You should be able to get the profile information, from the MainViewController, from the GIDGoogleUser instance, and set the profile button image (profileButton.image) property to user profile picture.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem has a customView property which you can set to UIImageView(image: yourImage)